number theory, binomial coefficients divisibility
Let $p$ be a prime number greater than $3$ and $n$ a positive integer. Suppose $\nu _p(n) = r$. Prove that $\dbinom{np}{p} - n$ is divisible by $p^{3+r}$
The problem is here: https://poti.impa.br/uploads/material_teorico/1cbcwjnxmh553.pdf
There is also a version of the problem but with $n=2$, which is proved in this paper, but I'm not sure how can I use it.
I don;t have a clear idea of what to do, I have that $\nu _p(\dbinom{np}{p}) = r$.

Apparently your $v_p(n) = r$ means $p^r$ is the largest power of $p$ which divides $n$.

FYI, I believe your v, i.e., $v$, should be \nu, i.e., $\nu$, instead, with this being the $p$-adic valuation function.

Yes, I didn't know that I should write it \nu. Edited

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the AoPS thread p^3|(kp choose k)-k, and also Prove that $\binom{ap}{p} \equiv a \pmod{ap}$, which deals with proving that $\binom{np}{p}-n$ is divisible by $p^{1+r}$.

Oh, that already proves the problem. Thanks John.
